# java server faces 1.2 error in eclipse not getting resloved in tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring, maven

[dynamic web module version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN1VG.png)
StackTrace:

```
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:QuoteBuilderAdmin' did not find a matching property.
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 7 2015 18:25:21 UTC
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.28.0
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_51-b16
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\wtpwebapps
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\endorsed
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\Balvinder\software\eclipse;;.
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:54 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:54 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1111 ms
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:57 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:57 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:57 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Nov 30 20:44:57 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:57 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3cd78871: defining beans [login,user,messageSource,viewResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 619 ms
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\webapps\docs
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\webapps\docs has finished in 30 ms
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\webapps\examples
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\webapps\examples has finished in 345 ms
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\webapps\host-manager
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\webapps\host-manager has finished in 40 ms
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\webapps\manager
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\webapps\manager has finished in 33 ms
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\webapps\ROOT
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory D:\Balvinder\balvinder\Quote builder\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\webapps\ROOT has finished in 23 ms
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Nov 30, 2015 8:44:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4546 ms
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring-dispatcher'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring-dispatcher': initialization started
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Nov 30 20:45:06 IST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3ac24067: defining beans [login,user,messageSource,viewResolver]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3cd78871
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/login] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/login.*] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/login/] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/changePasswordRequest] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/changePasswordRequest.*] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/changePasswordRequest/] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resetPasswordSendMail] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resetPasswordSendMail.*] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resetPasswordSendMail/] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/changePassword] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/changePassword.*] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/changePassword/] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/logOutPage] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/logOutPage.*] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/logOutPage/] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resetPassword] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resetPassword.*] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resetPassword/] onto handler 'login'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/editUser] onto handler 'user'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/editUser.*] onto handler 'user'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/editUser/] onto handler 'user'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/CreateUser] onto handler 'user'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/CreateUser.*] onto handler 'user'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/CreateUser/] onto handler 'user'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/saveUser] onto handler 'user'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/saveUser.*] onto handler 'user'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/saveUser/] onto handler 'user'
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring-dispatcher': initialization completed in 177 ms
Nov 30, 2015 8:45:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/QuoteBuilderAdmin/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
```

My code is
Web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.logiquebrain</groupId>
    <artifactId>QuoteBuilderAdmin</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>QuoteBuilderAdmin Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.37</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- optional -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-osgi</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-proxool</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>QuoteBuilderAdmin</finalName>
</build>
```

And spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
<bean id="login" class="controller.LoginController" />
<bean id="user" class="controller.UserController" />

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="WEB-INF/properties/messages" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I am using tomcat 8.0.
while compiling i am getting the following error:
I am getting error as(In problems: 2 error)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFHfN.png):

```
 - Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type JavaServer Faces 1.2 can not
   be installed : One or more constraints have not been
   satisfied.   QuoteBuilderAdmin       line 1  Maven Java EE Configuration
   Problem
 - Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type JavaServer Faces 1.2 requires
   Dynamic Web Module 2.5 or newer. QuoteBuilderAdmin       line 1  Maven Java
   EE Configuration Problem
```

Please help me to run my project.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please paste full stack trace

Comment: Which version of Dynamic Web Module does the project have?

Comment: Full stack is listed in first window(on top of this page), And Dynamic web module is 2.3(Snap Shot is attached on starting of this error, in very beginning).